# 22.04 install wiped 4 partitions leaving one with type ee GPT

Tags: partitioning, uefi

This is very frustrating, as i had manually
partitioned /dev/sda a 2T barracuda. I had
four partitions :

```
/dev/sda1 grub boot       (size 10Mb)
/dev/sda2 EFI type unknown  (size 1024 Mb)
/dev/sda3 swap type 82    (size  2048 Mb)
/dev/sda4 ext4 on (/)     (size 1.8 Tb)
```

After a over hour long installation, where
the last 45 minutes consisted of endless removal
of things like thunderbird-locales-es.deb
( I had chosen a minimal installation) during
reboot it worked all right. I chose to boot
the system from a rescue, and with fdisk -l
it only showed  one partition :

```
/dev/sda1 type ee (size 2 Tb )
```

And the strangest part is that my machine does
not know anything about UEFI .

Comment: Post this: `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` If you convert a MBR(msdos) to gpt it erases the drive and puts one entry in gpt's protective MBR as gpt, so old partition tools do not try to repartition drive. You can use gpt with UEFI or with BIOS with Ubuntu, but Windows requires MBR for BIOS boot and requires gpt for UEFI boot. Gpt has advantages & should be used.  But if system is so old as to not support UEFI (over 10 yrs old) then you probably need a light weight flavor. What brand/model system?